# sklearn train_test_split error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, arrays, reshape, logistic-regression, shapes

```
x = dummiesfinal.iloc[9]
y = dummiesfinal.iloc[0:8,10:47]
x = np.array(x).T.reshape(-1,1)
y = np.array(y)
np.shape(x)
(48, 1)
np.shape(y)
(8, 37)
plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.30)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-90e4256c22db> in <module>
      1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      2 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
----> 3 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.30)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2125         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
   2126 
-> 2127     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   2128 
   2129     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    291     """
    292     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 293     check_consistent_length(*result)
    294     return result
    295 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    254     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
    255     if len(uniques) > 1:
--> 256         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
    257                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    258 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [48, 8]
```

i am running a model on logistic regression but i am getting stuck at this point please suggest for the same

if there is a better other way to do it let me know as i have been stuck on the same code for long hours

thank you

Comment: For LogisticRegression to work, the number of rows (i.e. the number of samples) in X, y should be the same. In your case, the number of samples are 48 and 8 respectively. You could try changing that.

Comment: Can you specify the sizes of x = dummiesfinal.iloc[9] and y = dummiesfinal.iloc[0:8,10:47]?

Comment: @sotmot 
x = dummiesfinal.iloc[9] -------> target Variable
y = dummiesfinal.iloc[0:8,10:47] ------->predictorsRangeIndex: 45211 entries, 0 to 45210
Data columns (total 48 columns):

Comment: i am not getting the reshape too

Comment: you seem to be using iloc(). Were you planning on taking row values of dummiesfinal as x and y?

Comment: @sotmot no, not the rows but the columns

Comment: Oh. In that case, you need to change it to x = dummiesfinal[9] for x and correspondingly for y too. iloc() extracts rows of the dataframe.

Comment: @sotmot insted of doing like that i did this
x = dummiesfinal.y
y = dummiesfinal.drop('y', axis=1)

and it runs fine, but now i got theis error here
when i do model.fit(x,y)
y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (45211, 47) instead.

Comment: @sotmot thanks alot for the mistake i did there thanks to make me realize :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)